# how to remove from list using Lambda syntax

Tags: c#, list, lambda

Given:

```
List<Name> names = new List<Name>(); //list full of names

public void RemoveName(string name) {
   List<Name> n = names.Where(x => x.UserName == name);;
   names.Remove(n);
}
```

What's the Lambda syntax to execute the removal?

And how can I get indication of "success" if the function did remove or not?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
names.RemoveAll(x => x.UserName == name);
```

Note here that all the *lambda syntax* does is provide a `Predicate<T>`; lambda syntax is entirely unrelated to what it ends up *doing* with the lambda.

Or for a single match (see comments):

```
var found = names.Find(x => x.UserName == name);
if(found != null) names.Remove(found);
```

or:

```
var index = names.FindIndex(x => x.UserName == name);
if(index >= 0) names.RemoveAt(index);
```

Comment: i only want to remove one name, that is beeing send as an argu

Comment: @darko it will only remove those that match; however... I'll add an edit for single removal...

Comment: Nit picking, but for completeness; all of the above will blow up with a null inserted in the List. If that's a possibility, you'll need to null check in the lambda.

Comment: how can i get indication of "success" if the function did remove or not?

Comment: The `names.Find`/`names.Remove` approach is slower than the index-based approach, requiring on average 1.5 traversals through the list rather than 1. It would be better to put the faster of the two first and mention the slowdown of the alternative. In this case, there's no downside of the faster approach.

Answer (score 4):

```
var n = names.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserName == name)
if(n != null && n.UserName.length > 0)
{
 names.Remove(n);
}
```

OR

```
var n= names.Where(x => x.UserName == name).First();
names.Remove(n)
```

Comment: how can i get indication of "success" if the function did remove or not?

Comment: names.Remove(n) Returns:
//true if item is successfully removed; otherwise, false. This method also
//returns false if item was not found in the