# Remove object from two list by reference

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have a list 2 classes like that:

```
class Item1
{
}


class Item2
{
    public Item1 item;

    public Item2(Item1 it){
        item = it;
    }
}
```

Then i have a list with Item1:

```
List<Item1> item1list;
```

And another list with Item2:

```
List<Item2> item2list;
```

I did my lists like that:

```
var it = new Item1();
item1list.Add(it);
item2list.Add(new Item2(it));
```

Now, I just want to delete an element from item1list and lost the reference (get a null) in item2list, like that:

```
item1list.Remove(it); // item1list lost the element
item2list.Select(i => (search query)) // Gives a null result
```

By now the item2list keeps a copy of my Item1 object.

Comment: You still have `it` reference, so it should be possible to find an item: `item2list.RemoveAll(i => i.Item1 == it)` ([credits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14358396/1997232)).

Comment: @Sinatr is there any other possibilities ? I want to avoid that

Comment: Make sure you are not changing the value with : item = it

Comment: `I want to lost the reference in the second list after removing from first list.` that's not supported by default by C# or LINQ. You need to write your own logic to keep the lists in sync. `item2list.RemoveAll` as suggested by Sinatr is one of the approaches.

Comment: Your second list is of a different type (`List<Item2>`) than your first list (`List<Item1>`).  It contains different objects (your `it` in your first list is `new Item1()`, while the item in the second list is `new Item2(it)`).  I'm not sure how you want to keep them in sync without a lot of code.  Just because there is no longer a reference to the object that `it` references in the first list doesn't mean that object doesn't exist.  As long as there are references to that object (and your second item (the `Item2` instance) references it), the object will hang around and not be collected

Comment: Well, if i change a value of an object in the first like, the second list will get the information even if the two lists are different type

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Ok so maybe i should use RemoveAll or use just one list and get the other with this one.

Comment: @Flydog57 If i understand the reference just pass from a list to another ?

Comment: No, your second list doesn't reference the item in the first list, it references an object that references that item.  If you want, you can write code that removes an item from the first list, and, at the same time, looks for items in the second list that includes object references to that item and removes them as well.  Look at @Sinatr's comment

Comment: @Flydog57ok got it i'll do it in another way. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I renamed your classes (because my head just rejects a class named "Item1").  So, here's your original classes, slightly modified:

```
class Class1 {}

class Class2 {
    public Class1 Item { get; }

    public Class2(Class1 item) {
        Item = item;
    }
}
```

And then some code that uses them:

```
 var itemList1 = new List<Class1>();
 var itemList2 = new List<Class2>();

 var item1 = new Class1();
 var item2 = new Class2(item1);

 itemList1.Add(item1);
 itemList2.Add(item2);

 //you could put this in a method and do it as a single operation:
 itemList1.Remove(item1);
 itemList2.RemoveAll(i => i.Item == item1);
```